# "Deselect On Nothing" python script

Tags: python, shortcut

I am trying to emulate "view3d.select" shortcut but I don't know how to emulate "Deselect On Nothing" option of "view3d.select". Do you guys know how?I am using blender 2.93.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.view3d.html#bpy.ops.view3d.select

Comment: Please [edit] any new information into question.

Comment: thanx, but I've just realized it wont work.

what I want to do is, clicking vertex and moving it pressing mouse button without pressing G key, so I use this script.

bpy.ops.view3d.select('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
bpy.ops.transform.translate("INVOKE_DEFAULT")

I need to omit all bpy.ops.view3d.select options in order to make it work in python script.That script needs "deselect_all" operation to make it perfect but seems it's dead end now.